# The argument type 'Iterable<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Gif>'

Tags: flutter

I was trying to use the Giphy API to start using APIs in flutter but I got this bug and I don’t know how to fix it.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<Iterable>(
        future: _listadoGifs,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView(
              children: _listGifs(snapshot.data!),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("error");
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I do not use a List because I use the following class:

```
List<Widget> _listGifs(List<Gif> data) {
    List<Widget> gifs = [];

    for (var gif in data) {
      gifs.add(Card(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network(gif.url.toString()),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(gif.name.toString()),
          ),
        ],
      )));
    }
    return gifs;
  }
```

Comment: Can you add more information about "_listadoGifs" what's happen there :)

Comment: It is a variable that I use to wait for the info request to be resolved and I have it as follows: late Future<List<Gif>> _listadoGifs;